The nouns or noun phrases to describe people working in certain industries
I find it challenging to refer to the groups of people in this chart. Here are the best versions I've come up with so far. I still find them lengthy and unhelpful, but their saving grace is their broadness.

Education training: educators
Education training/Hotel industry/Medical: people who work in the education/hotel/medical industry.
Medical: Is calling this group "doctors and nurses" broad enough?
Construction: people working for construction companies
Business: people who conduct business for a living?



Education and medicine are sectors rather than industries, and the medical sector isn't just doctors and nurses but administrators, specialists such as radiographers, receptionists etc.

I think you need the term sector. This is the broadest term to describe each area of industry.
Your groups would probably be defined as

Education sector
Hospitality sector
Healthcare sector
Construction sector

"Self employed" and "unemployed" do not define areas of work.
This page has a decent list of sectors for any others you may wish to look up.
